# Accessory View background disappears when selecting a table cell

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, uilabel, background-color

I'm using a text label with a background as my `cell.accessoryView`. When the `Table` gets selected, my accessory view background (`label.backgroundColor`) disappears. I'm able to restore the label's text color by setting `label.highlightedTextColor`. But I couldn't restore its background color. Is there something like `highlightedTextBackgroundcolor` or `selectedBackgroundView`?

```
UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:DISTANCE_BUBBLE];
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:indicatorImage];


distanceLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:cell.accessoryView.bounds];

distanceLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
distanceLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
distanceLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
distanceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:DISTANCE_BUBBLE]];
distanceLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
distanceLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.accessoryView=distanceLabel;
```

Comment: provide cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass UITableViewCell.

It'll give you much more control and keep your cellForRowAtIndexPath method tidier.

Answer (score 1):

Create your accessory view as a view that contains the background in one view and the label.

Answer (score 0):

**write Following code may be helpful for you.**

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
**Edited Code** //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**For Display backGroundColor of cell Accessory View**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foobar"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    }
    UIImageView *colorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [colorView setImage:image];

    [cell setAccessoryView:colorView];

    cell.textLabel.text=[self.listOfFrnd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**Display Cell BackGround Image of cell Accessory View**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Foobar"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Foobar"];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    UIImageView *colorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [colorView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"]];

    [cell setAccessoryView:colorView];


    cell.textLabel.text=[self.listOfFrnd objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

After I tried, found that if you take more then one cell **accessoryView** then it display only one **accessoryView**. I am not sure that i am right but may be it is true :)
Thanks :)

Comment: i dont understand your problem clearly ..you want if you select specific row then **distanceLabel** is display with it's backGroundColor

Comment: add `[cell.accessoryView retain];` to method